# Store frequently used strings in object - Scala

Tags: string, scala

I would like to store frequently used strings inside an object. On top of this, I would also like to conveniently add a functionality similar to the mkString function's, where if there are two objects of a certain type, they can be appended with a certain character or set of characters.

Here is what I have until now:

```
import org.scalatest._

class MyKey(val inputValue: String) {
  val value = inputValue

  def + (otherMyKeys: MyKey): MyKey = {
    new MyKey(this.value + "." + otherMyKeys.value)
  }

  override def toString(): String = this.value.toString
}

object MyKeys {
  val SPARK = new MyKey("spark")
  val JSON = new MyKey("json")
  val TITLE = new MyKey("title")
  val URI = new MyKey("uri")
}

class MyKeySpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "MyKey" should "not put a fullstop character when there is only one value" in {
    MyKeys.SPARK should not equal("spark")
    MyKeys.SPARK.toString() should equal("spark")
  }

  it should "put a fullstop character between multiple keys" in {
    val actual = MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.JSON + MyKeys.TITLE + MyKeys.URI
    val expected = "spark.json.title.uri"
    actual should not equal(expected)
    actual.toString() should equal(expected)
  }

  it should "work even when the same key is repeated multiple times" in {
    val actual = MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.SPARK
    val expected = "spark.spark.spark"
    actual should not equal(expected)
    actual.toString() should equal(expected)
  }
}
```

This solution is elegant in using the "+" function but does not work without a toString. Is there a more elegant solution where I would not even have to use the toString function? The aim is to make a string like "spark.json.spark.spark" as `MyKeys.SPARK + MyKey.JSON + MyKey.SPARK + MyKey.SPARK`

I can use the mkString function to do the same thing but that, I feel, is not super intuitive. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you might do is define an `apply()` method instead of overriding the `toString()`.

```
def apply(): String = this.value
```

Then you get...

```
MyKeys.SPARK should not equal("spark")
MyKeys.SPARK() should equal("spark")
```

... etc.

---

The problem with your design is that anything of type `MyKey` is, obviously, not a `String`. It's *almost* a `String`, but still needs some catalyst to make the transition, something like `.toString()` or, as I suggested, the hidden .`apply()` method.

You could make `MyKeys.SPARK` a real `String`, but the `+` method for `String` already has a meaning and can't be redefined. If you were OK using a different operator then it could be done.

```
object MyKeys {
  val SPARK = "spark"
  val JSON  = "json"
  val TITLE = "title"
  val URI   = "uri"
}

implicit class Dotter(str :String) {
  def *(append :String) = str + "." + append
}

MyKeys.SPARK * MyKeys.JSON * MyKeys.SPARK  //res0: String = spark.json.spark
```

Comment: When I plugged in this into my code, it didn't satisfy the requirements. Could you please clarify? I want to get a string which equals "spark.json.title.uri" when I concatenate* by doing `MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.JSON + MyKeys.TITLE + MyKeys.URI`. My test case shows the current state, not the desired state. The desired state would be `actual should equal(expected)` in test number 2.

Comment: Re-read my answer. I'm suggesting `actual() should equal(expected)`. That's `actual()` **not** `actual`.

Comment: Yes but is there a way to get `actual should equal(expected)`? The reason is that if the frequently used items were function calls, the code would just be more verbose. `MyKeys.SPARK() + MyKeys.JSON() + MyKeys.TITLE() + MyKeys.URI()` is harder to read than `MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.JSON + MyKeys.TITLE + MyKeys.URI` right? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using implicit conversions for this?

```
class MyKey(val value: String) {
  def + (otherMyKeys: MyKey): MyKey = {
    new MyKey(this.value + "." + otherMyKeys.value)
  }
}

object MyKey {
  implicit def myKeyToString(myKey: MyKey): String = myKey.value
}

object MyKeys {
  val SPARK = new MyKey("spark")
  val JSON = new MyKey("json")
}

val result: String = MyKeys.SPARK + MyKeys.JSON // spark.json
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me: https://pastebin.com/RBFJhpSN What did I do wrong? 

I also tried this but it does not equal the string "spark". I do not want to call the toString method on the object. https://pastebin.com/XZg19eZ0